# Validating selected checkboxes (array) with 'in'

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation

I have the following checkboxes in my form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="likes_turtles" class="col-md-3 control-label">Likes Turtles</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="likes_turtles[]" value="Yes"> Yes
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="likes_turtles[]" value="No"> No
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="likes_turtles[]" value="Maybe so"> Maybe so
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, they are an array of items because I want to allow selection of multiple items.

I am trying make it so that the checked items must be valid.

Here is my validation rule:

```
[likes_turtles] => required|in:Yes,No,Maybe so
```

The problem is, I'm getting the following error when I check any or all of these items:

```
The selected likes turtles is invalid.
```

How do I make laravel simply ensure any items in the request array `likes_turtles` belong to the specified list e.g. `Yes,No,Maybe so`

Comment: What if you split that rule and add `.*` after the field name for the second rule: `"likes_turtles" => "required", "likes_turtles.*" => "in:Yes,No,Maybe so"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation on validating arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays), you could do it like this:

```
[
    "likes_turtles" => "required", 
    "likes_turtles.*" => "in:Yes,No,Maybe so"
]
```

Comment: Worked awesome. Thank you!